# Shopify - Embedded App - User session and webhooks

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I'm fairly new to Shopify development and I'm trying to understand the best way to address our requirement. Apologies if some of these are basic questions.

The intent is to build an embedded public application that is intended to:

1. Have a floating component that's present on all pages on the online
   store.
2. React to the user journey e.g. do stuff when the user adds
   items to cart, completes a checkout, etc.
3. Send events to our server through the journey to allow our server to provide relevant
   info, regardless of the store theme.
4. Have the ability to do this at an individual session level i.e. not all users will have the same experience.

I had a few questions around this:

1. Will it be possible to add the script to the main theme page and
   have it load on all pages?
2. Is there a better alternative, particularly if the integration is supposed to be light-touch for admins?
3. What is the best way to get access to the individual user session from the app (assuming we can request the appropriate permissions as a part of the app installation)?
4. Is app bridge and session token required for this?
5. Is it possible to build this app using Angular? I understand Shopify framework is API-based and in theory any UI framework should work, but will a deeper linking with the user session be possible with Angular?
6. If we get enable web hooks for the various events, would it be a reliable way to detect events happening in the user journey? If so, what will be the correlation id between the events from the app and the web hooks?
7. Is it possible to detect the page the user is in, regardless of the theme? For example: Is there a way to identify that the user has added an item to the cart regardless of the theme used or is a webhook our best bet for those events?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There is one thing you can do that would support most of your needs. Create an App, and set that App up with a Proxy. Shopify will then support the customer centric store theme to use a secure Ajax callback to your App using the proxy. So you can always call a proxy like **/tool/customer_check** with or without a customer ID from anywhere in the store.

You can imagine how powerful that is. You can return Liquid or more commonly, JSON. Boom! You're in business.

Of course, there are alternatives, all with the caveat your mileage may vary. None of this is predicated on any particular tech stack, meaning you can use what you like and know.